# How can I prevent AliasExistsException while verifying phone number and email in Cognito User Pool?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I configured a Cognito User Pool with *"Option 1: Multiple sign-in attributes (alias attributes)"*. I configured phone_number and email as alias attributes. The document says *"Only the last user who has verified the attribute can sign in with it"*. I first confirm account and verify email attribute with ConfirmSignUp API. Then I use VerifyUserAttribute API to verify phone number. ConfirmSignup API has ForceAliasCreation parameter so that I can override an existing alias. However VerifyUserAttribute doesn't have ForceAliasCreation parameter. This creates two problems:

- After sign up and confirmation, I can't verify Phone Number if there is an existing alias
- After UptateUserAttributes I can't verify Phone Number or E-Mail Address if there is an existing alias

When I try VerifyUserAttribute API it throws AliasExistsException. How can I prevent AliasExistsException and force alias creation in these scenarios?

Best Regards